# Nested function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-function

[image]

I am new to javascript and jQuery. I am writing the following code to edit a portion of my web page. It is working perfect when I click on #edit_case first time but after clicking #cancel that returns me back. The #edit_case does not work.. What is wrong with this piece of code?

```
$("#edit_case").click(function(){  

    var oldHTML = $("#editable").html();
    var newHTML;

    newHTML = "<div class='panel-body' id='edit_fields'></div> <div class='panel-footer' id='footer-bottons'></div>"
    $("#editable").html(newHTML);
    $('#footer-bottons').html('<div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="save">Save</button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="cancel">Cancel</button></div>');

    $("#cancel").click(function(){  

        $("#editable").html(oldHTML);

    });
});
```

My HTML markup is like:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" id="editable">
     <div class="panel-body">
         Drop-down code 
         <li><a id='edit_case'>Edit</a><li>

         Panel-Body Code... 

     </div>
Panel footer
</div>
```

When I click on Edit, the same text input fields appear as that on stackoverflow.com. On first time, Edit link works fine but when I cancel Edit both Edit and Delete do not work. I think click event is not occurring as I also have tried a check on it by using alert('test') and it isn't appeared after clicking on #cancel. Is this a problem of unbinding event? If it is, how would I correct it?

Comment: Is there still the element with id edit_case after you click Cancel button?

Comment: What does this mean: _"that returns me back out of fields"_. Also, _"The #edit_case does not work.. What is wrong with this piece of code?"_ You haven't told us what it's supposed to do, so it's hard for us to tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for comments... I have added more details to it..

Comment: @HassanSaqib my answer has been updated. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the cancel button was not in the dom at first and since you are removing the edit_case, you need to do it with an ".on" put this code in the loading, not in the click event. if you put it in the click event, you will have multiple event that will be registered.

with working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2hjr6g94/

```
$(document).on('click','#cancel',function(){  
        $("#editable").html(oldHTML);
    });

var oldHTML = $("#editable").html();

$(document).on('click','#edit_case',function(){  
    var oldHTML = $("#editable").html();
    var newHTML;

    newHTML = "<div class='panel-body' id='edit_fields'></div> <div class='panel-footer' id='footer-bottons'></div>"
    $("#editable").html(newHTML);
    $('#footer-bottons').html('<div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="save">Save</button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="cancel">Cancel</button></div>');

});
```

Comment: this is true, and I did not think o that. Or you could use the "live" binder couldn't you?

Comment: No effects with this solution as well.

Comment: @HassanSaqib I would suggest that you removed the id selector and used the class selector instead. Since you are adding dynamic information, your code could be used more than once. Not sure if it will solve your problem but... can you add a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working fiddle, and a all the code. You were missing also the .on on the "edit_case" since it was removed and added later in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

After running it once, the new html is in the variable value of "oldHtml". You need to store the old HTML outside of this functionality, so it is preserved.

Here is the process you are doing right now:

1. Get html.
2. Load new html.
3. Get html (now new html).
4. load oldHtml (still new html).

oldHtml gets overridden and stored everytime this function is called.

Comment: Thanks Casey for reply. The oldHtml is preserving in my case. I have added more details on it..